# Return type based on value of input parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

In C++11 is there a way to implement a `sqrt` function that works for both positive and negative `double` input values? I would like the return type to be `std::complex<double>` if the input is negative and a `double` if it is positive. I realize the simple solution is to just always return `std::complex<double>` but this is not what I am looking for.

Below I have an example of my first attempt, however this does not compile due to the presence of `a` in the return type:

```
inline decltype((a > 0)?(double):(std::complex<double>)) sqrt(const double& a)
{
    if(a > 0)
    {
        return std::sqrt(a);
    }
    else
    {
        return ((std::complex<double>(0.0,1.0))*std::sqrt(-a));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I have this function in a namespace to avoid collisions with `std`.

Comment: Declaring it as `inline auto sqrt(const double& a) -> decltype((a > 0)?(double):(std::complex<double>))` should work.

Comment: @LoganMurphy Good point. I should change that to `std::sqrt()`.

Comment: @pwny, no, it shouldn't.

Comment: Types are compile-time, function arguments are run-time. See the problem?

Comment: c++ is a statically typed language: types are determined at compile time. So no, there's no way for the return type to be contingent on the value of a parameter that can vary at runtime.

Comment: You can specify the return type based on input *type*, but not the input *value*.

Comment: @Xeo Casey: That makes sense.

Comment: @maverik Yeah I have no idea what I was thinking...

Comment: template specialize? Its more cleaner and easier to maintain

Comment: @user814628: Using template specialization isn't going to help here. You're still stuck with attempting to deduce a type (which happens at compile time) based on a value that isn't known until run time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

Types are compile-time constructs, and your function's type is fixed at compile-time.

Were the argument provided as a `constexpr` "constant expression", then you might have used templates to solve your problem. But, with dynamic inputs, this is simply not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could return a `boost::variant<double, std::complex<double>>` (since the decision has to be made at runtime), but that seems like adding a lot of complexity to your code for no real gain.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, and probably more importantly, probably wouldn't be useful even if you could do it.

Since the function *can* return a complex number, the calling code needs to be prepared to  process a complex number. If your code needs to be able to process complex numbers in any case, it almost certainly makes more sense to always return a complex number, and if the input was positive it'll be of the form `X + 0i` (i.e., the imaginary part will equal 0).

In theory, you could do this in a language that supported dynamic typing -- but even with most of them, `sqrt` is basically statically typed. If the input you provide is a real number, the result will also be a real number, and if the input was negative the result will typically be a `NaN` or something on that order. If (and only if) you provide the input as a complex number will you receive  a complex number as the result.